# Symfony3 - Email not sent from a Command

Tags: php, symfony, email, command, swiftmailer

I can't sent e-mail from a Command in Symfony3 in prod.

My code :

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('A subject')
        ->setFrom('email@site.com')
        ->setTo('email@site.com')
        ->setBody('content', 'text/html');

    $mailer = $this->getContainer()->get('mailer');
    $mailer->send($message);
```

Config.yml

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host:      '%mailer_host%'
    username:  '%mailer_user%'
    password:  '%mailer_password%'
    port:      '%mailer_port%'
    encryption: '%mailer_encryption%'
    spool: { type: memory }
```

Parameters.yml

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: myhostfromovh
mailer_encryption: null
mailer_port: 587
mailer_user: myuser
mailer_password: mypassword
```

I got no error but no e-mail received in my mailbox. :(

Moreover, when I write in command line :

```
php app/console swiftmailer:email:send
```

I got :

```
[2017-12-22 13:31:12] app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host myhostfromovh [Connection refused #111]
```

I changed my custom host **myhostfromovh** by smtp.gmail.com or ns0.ovh.net (with PORT and USER / PASSWORD), nothing to do, it doesn't work. :-(

BUT ! When I execute the same code in a Controller, no problem, I receive the mail. So I don't understand.

Help me ! \o/

Comment: are you executing your code outside of symfony context ?

Comment: Can you add the logs of var/logs/prod.log and var/logs/dev.log ?

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled an email queue in your swiftmail this means that the emails will be queued and send during the kernel event terminate (after you already send the response to the client).

You should have the errors of your controller on var/logs/prod.log

It seems your host is not allowed to connect to that host:port. Possible reasons?

- Your IP has been banned
- Wrong ip/port (Configuration)
- Service provider/Enterprise/University firewall block outgoing smtp connections (quite common nowadays)

Install mailcatcher https://mailcatcher.me/ and try to send emails to your local smtp server.

Comment: I used https://mailcatcher.me/. It works for php app/console swiftmailer:email:send, but when I execute my command, no email in MailCatcher... But with the Controller (same code), it works...

Comment: run: php bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send

Comment: Did you deleted the cache after any change on the parameters/configuration file on both environtment prod and dev?

Comment: php bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send  => 0 emails sent ;; Yes I removed cache for prod and dev

Comment: Maybe parameters are not the same when you’re using the console. Did you check that ?

Comment: Logs => php.DEBUG: Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ns0.ovh.net:587 (Connection refused) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\SilencedErrorContext: {\"severity\":2,\"file\":\"/home/lmdappcoka/www/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php\",\"line\":266})"} []

Comment: I checked the parameters... In local, the command runs correctly and I receive the mail. In prod, I got "Connection refused".

Comment: This is not a symfony issue. Your server and port is wrong or your IP has been banned. If you try to connect manually from you server and from your localhost to the same server you will find out the answer. If both fails wrong server or port. If only your prod server fails, your ip/server is not allowed to access there. I'm assuming you cleared the production cache here.